# Using ThunderBolt 27" Display with a Second VGA Display not working in Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have purchased a ThunderBolt display and is lovely.

I have it setup with a second monitor using VGA in OSX to have 3 monitors (inc 1 of the 15" MacBook Pro display)

So my setup is as follows:
MacBook Pro 15"
27" ThunderBolt Display
WD ThunderBolt MyBook Hard Drive (Has two Thunderbolt ports, which allows me to extend display)
Normal Samsung 23" Monitor connected to WD MyBook Hard Drive with the normal ThunderBolt/Mini Display to VGA adaptor

This setup works perfectly in OSX without any issues, however I cannot get the VGA monitor to work when booted into Windows 7 using a native BootCamp partition.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or has managed to get this setup working in Windows at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yo.  I've tried with every possible scenario.  I found a note on Apple's site somewhere that stated that only one tb monitor is allowed for use in windows 7.  So...  Until they update the drivers for Win7 you can't get it working.  However...  If you use a TB Imac and add a second monitor to it, that does work as I have that setup at home.

Answer (score 1):

My current setup is now to run Windows in VMWare as I get the two external monitors and my laptop monitor to work in Windows, which is fantastic.

So I am now very happy :)

Cheers,
Warren